# get two different test result of phantomjs with tap format on one URL

Tags: jenkins, phantomjs, tap

I'm using phantomjs for test my site on Jenkins, and confused with got the different result of the TAP within two builds, There is nothing changed. 
However, The result of Junit xml are same as we expected.

Can someone explain or help to me? Thank you very much!

This is what I compared the result of TAP.

```
3,4c3,4
< ok 1 B (82) overall score
< not ok 2 D (68) ynumreq: Make fewer HTTP requests
---
> not ok 1 C (78) overall score
> ok 2 B (80) ynumreq: Make fewer HTTP requests


24c21
<   message: There are 50 static components without a far-future expiration date.
---
>   message: There are 45 static components without a far-future expiration date.

77c69,81
< ok 6 A (100) ycompress: Compress components with gzip
---
> not ok 6 F (12) ycompress: Compress components with gzip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "there is nothing changed", there probably is indeed a difference somewhere.

There are many possible reasons why you might get different results each time for an HTTP-based test suite:

- Your test cases have changed between the two runs.
- You're testing against a live web server, whose content changed between the tests.
- You're testing against a live web server, whose content was not yet fully deployed by the time you made first the test, but was for the second.
- The hostname of the live URL you're testing resolves to multiple servers, and the load balancer is sending you to a different server each time, each with different content.
- There is some form of caching happening in your test client.
- The server is serving dynamic content, e.g. based on time of day, client IP address, ...

The JUnit XML output file may however be the same, for example if you didn't do a "clean" build and delete the XML file at the start of the build. Perhaps your test tool then refuses to write a new XML file if there's already one existing.